# Loop 3 images from my Div background-image Property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code to loop images but based on an Img source, but how to improve it to make it work for the "background-image" property of a div?

HTML

```
<div id="section2"></div>
```

CSS

```
#section2 {
background-image: 'url(..images/banner1.jpg');
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
(function() {     
var i = 1;
var pics = [ "images/banner1.jpg", "images/banner2.jpg", "images/banner3.jpg" ];
var el = document.getElementById('section2');  
function toggle() {
    el.src = pics[i];           
    i = (i + 1) % pics.length;  
}
setInterval(toggle, 3000);
})();             
  </script>
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: If I understand your right, try to use el.style.backgroundImage instead of el.src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use CSS classes instead of sources.

**JS:**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
(function() {     
var i = 1;
var classes = [ "bgd-1", "bgd-2", "bgd-3" ]; // adjusted
var el = document.getElementById('section2');  
function toggle() {
    el.className = classes[i]; // adjusted           
    i = (i + 1) % classes.length; // adjusted 
}
setInterval(toggle, 3000);
})();             
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
#section2.bgd-1 {
    background-image: url('..images/banner1.jpg');
} 

#section2.bgd-2 {
    background-image: url('..images/banner2.jpg');
} 

#section2.bgd-3 {
    background-image: url('..images/banner3.jpg');
}
```

Note:

Use `el.className += ' ' + classes[i];` to append a class name instead of replacing all element classes.

Comment: thanks @lessugar but for some reason is not working, I think the background-image should be instead url('../images/banner2.jpg'); right? but still:( not working

Comment: Yep, the CSS was wrong, edited it. However, the script works for me. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/3pg0tg2n/. Getting any errors in the console maybe? Did you set the `width` and `height` on the `#section2` div?

Comment: @lessugar my friend now is working but first time doesn't show the 1st screen, and jumps directly to the second one after not showing any of the screens, and by finishing the 3 screens moving back to the first one, and this time the first one is showing, but why not in the first loop:(?

Comment: Hard to say without the whole CSS/HTML code. Also, is the source of the first image correct? Maybe a typo somewhere? Can be lots of things. Take a look at the fiddle from my previous comment, and try to figure out what's different about your implementation. Good luck.

Comment: done pal:D! simply added the background too again to the original section style! :) and is showing original bg first and then the other 3! yey! thanks!!